# Read from CSV, compare list values to CSV columns

Tags: python, csv

I am in the process of creating a room booking system. The first part of my program takes the users inputs of date, lesson period, and class size.

The class size is taken and compared with a CSV file that outputs in a list, the rooms that the class can fit in - this works correctly.

The next part of my code then takes the date and lesson period, looks in the bookings CSV, if the date the user has entered (the day they wish to book) and the lesson period that has entered (time they wish to book) matches the 'date'/'lesson period' columns in the bookings CSV, it looks what room these are in, then removes these taken rooms, from the list of suggested rooms, to the rooms they can actually book. So far my code is:

```py
check_date = "12/01/2019"
check_period = "Lesson 3"

check_room = "G11"

list1 = listSuitableRooms
print(list1)

with open("Bookings.csv") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    header = next(reader)

for line in reader:
    for i in range(1, len(list1)):
        if line[2] == check_date and line[4] == check_period:
            if list1[i] == line[6]:
                print("bookings:")
                print(line)
                print()
                print("rooms that fit are:")
                list1.remove(list1[i])
                print(list1)


            else:
                print("rooms available are:")
                print(list1)
```

but it is ignoring the conditions of the list and not removing the busy rooms. Preferably without using pandas - I only need to import CSV.

Answer (score 0):

You may have white space in your column name, and your range should start at 0.

```
with open("/tmp/Bookings.csv") as f: 
    reader = csv.reader(f) 
    header = next(reader) 

    for line in reader: 
        for i in range(0, len(list1)): 
            if line[2].strip() == check_date and line[4].strip() == check_period: 
                if list1[i] == line[6].strip(): 
                    print("bookings:") 
                    print(line) 
                    print() 
                    print("rooms that fit are:") 
                    list1.remove(list1[i]) 
                    print(list1) 
                else: 
                    print("rooms available are:") 
                    print(list1)
```

Comment: but line is the line of the csv file, and my code works while the room is a single value, whereas doesnt work when its the list to look throug one by one? if i change to get this code, i get the error: line 51, in <module>
    tab = line.strip().split(",")
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'strip'

Comment: @NatashaBayliss, change `tab=line.strip().split('',")` to `tab=str(line).strip().split(",")`. Your `AttributeError` says, that the `line` is a `list` object such as `[1,2,3,4]` but not a `string` object such as `one,two,three`.

Comment: Could you give the two first lines of your csv file ?

Comment: yea so the bookings CSV goes as follows: First Name, Last Name, Date, Subject, Period, Class size, Room - examples of values = Tash, Tester, 12/01/2019, ICT, Lesson 3, 25, G5a

Comment: @Oysiyl it still isn't printing the new list with the removed values where a booking already exists?

Comment: It may not be the main problem, but your range should start at 0 (for i in range(0, len(list1))). Additionally, if your csv is like you described it, you should add ".strip()" at the end of line[2], line[4] and line[6] (in order to remove the unwanted white space). I updated my answer.